# что после "Heroku | Welcome to your new app!"?

Tags: python, django, heroku

я выложил свой блог с гитхаба 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

все файлы есть 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я уже не знаю сколько мучаюсь, ничего не понимаю , у меня сайт готов а все документации не про то вообще , помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Я не эксперт, но разве на heroku не через gunicorn деплоят?

Comment: вот и я не эксперт тоже

Comment: попрубую как вы сказали

Comment: на сайте хероку только добаление юникорна